# What is the MSO code for a color block with text above it?

Tags: html, email, colors, footer

I am trying to build a custom email footer for Marketing Cloud. It has a navy blue background color with text over top of it. The footer renders correctly in Litmus tests for everything except Outlook 2016 (Win 7), Outlook 365, and Outlook 2019 desktop versions, where it is a bit more narrow than the rest of the email. I'm having trouble getting the MSO coding right. Can you help me?

This is the footer code that I have now:

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:#fff;">
    
    <!-- FOOTER CONTENT -->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="background:#17253c;" width="100%">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
            <td  style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://www.netjets.com/en-gb/?go=contact&utm_content=footer2&utm_campaign=NJE_Prospect_Newsletter_Q420_English" target="_blank" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none">Contact Us</a><br><a style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration:none">NetJets Europe <br> 5 Young Street, London, UK, W8 5EH.</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td  style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px; font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height: 19px; color: #ffffff; padding:0px 0px 25px 0px;">
                This email was sent by: 
                <span>%%Member_Busname%%<br>
                %%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%% %%Member_Country%%</span>
                <br>
                <br> Legal notice: Copyright 2021 NetJets Inc. All rights reserved.<br>
                <a href="https://www.netjets.com/en-gb/privacy" alias="Privacy Policy" target="_blank" style="font-size:12px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Privacy Policy</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" target="_blank" style="font-size:12px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Update Profile</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" target="_blank" style="font-size:12px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Manage Subscriptions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" target="_blank" style="font-size:12px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-weight:bold;">Unsubscribe</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
</html>
```

I tried to add the following in at line 4, but it still isn't quite right.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style=" border: 0;display: inline-block;position: absolute; width: 480pt; height:300pt;">
<v:fill  opacity="0%" color="#17253c”  />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need javascript to do that correctly.

Comment: How might I do that?